# Crossbar.io configure WSGI for Django app

Tags: django, wsgi, crossbar

I am experimenting with Crossbar.io 0.10.4 and Django 1.6.11, trying to follow the [example here](http://crossbar.io/docs/Adding-Real-Time-to-Django-Applications/#crossbar.io). The code shows you can configure Crossbar.io to serve up the Django app at "/" -- but when I try that in my configuration, I get a Python import error:

```
ApplicationError: ApplicationError('crossbar.error.invalid_configuration', args = (u"WSGI app module 'apache/django.wsgi' import failed: Import by filename is not supported. - Python search path was ....
```

My config.json is here:

```
{
   "controller": {
   },
   "workers": [
      {
         "type": "router",
         "realms": [
            {
               "name": "backstage-producer",
               "roles": [
                  {
                     "name": "anonymous",
                     "permissions": [
                        {
                           "uri": "*",
                           "publish": false,
                           "subscribe": true,
                           "call": false,
                           "register": false
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ],
         "transports": [
            {
               "type": "web",
               "endpoint": {
                  "type": "tcp",
                  "port": 8080
               },
               "paths": {
                   "/": {
                     "type": "wsgi",
                     "module": "apache/django.wsgi",
                     "object": "application"
                  },
                  "ws": {
                     "type": "websocket",
                     "debug": false
                  },
                  "notify": {
                     "type": "publisher",
                     "realm": "backstage-producer",
                     "role": "anonymous"
                  },
                  "static": {
                     "type": "static",
                     "directory": "../static"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Where the Python paths searched do *not* include my Django project directory. Typically I append my specific project directories to sys.path in my wsgi file, but apparently that workflow doesn't work with Crossbar.io. Trying a relative import fails (need to specify "package" argument) as does full path (same import by filename error as above).

Removing the definition for "/" does not work, because Crossbar.io complains that it must be defined.

How can I set this up properly with Crossbar.io? My apache/django.wsgi file is below, for reference:

```
ALLDIRS = ['/usr/local/pythonenv/myapp/lib/python2.6/site-packages']

import os
import sys
import site

# from https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments

sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/myapp/myapp_main/')
sys.path.insert(1, '/var/www/myapp/')

prev_sys_path = list(sys.path)
for directory in ALLDIRS:
    site.addsitedir(directory)

new_sys_path = []
for item in list(sys.path):
    if item not in prev_sys_path:
        new_sys_path.append(item)
        sys.path.remove(item)

sys.path[:0] = new_sys_path

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp_main.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

----UPDATE 1------

Per Daniel's suggestion, I changed the file to just wsgi.py and my config to use the Python module path, not the filename / directory path. Config then looked like this:

```
"paths": {
       "/": {
         "type": "wsgi",
         "module": "apache.wsgi",
         "object": "application"
      },
```

Throws the same exception:

```
ApplicationError: ApplicationError('crossbar.error.invalid_configuration', args = (u"WSGI app module 'apache.wsgi' import failed: No module named apache.wsgi - Python search path was
```

My directory structure is:

```
  Project
    |- apache
    |     |-__init__.py
    |     |-wsgi.py
    |-.crossbar
          |-config.json
```

-------UPDATE 2-------

The only solution (read "hack") I have found is to hard-code my project path into `crossbar/worker/router.py` so that it is included in the Python search path list:

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/myapp/myapp_main/')
sys.path.insert(1, '/var/www/myapp/')
```

Seems like there should be a better way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is telling you that you have a file path in the setting that points to your WSGI file, whereas you need a Python module path. Your WSGI file should actually be a file called "wsgi.py" inside your project directory (which presumably is "apache", which is a strange name for a project that explicitly is not using Apache).

```
               "/": {
                 "type": "wsgi",
                 "module": "apache.wsgi",
                 "object": "application"
              },
```

**Update** So I found the [config docs](http://crossbar.io/docs/Native-Worker-Shared-Options/) at last: they really don't go out of their way to make it easy, like actually providing an index. Oh well.

It looks like you can provide an `options` hash to the router configuration including a `pythonpath` setting:

```
"workers": [
      {
         "type": "router",
         "options": {
             "pythonpath": ["/var/myapp/myapp_main/", "/var/myapp"]
         },
         ...
         "transports": {
             ...
```

Comment: Thanks for response -- changing the extension does not work (updated info above on config and errors). Haha, and yes, it is a weird name, playing around with a legacy app...

Comment: Ah, thanks!! I did not see that in the doc...great find. Works like a charm now.